# how to declare type in database in laravel in one column

Tags: laravel, migration, database-migration, laravel-8, sqldatatypes

[this image is show the my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN7wN.png)

i want try to type of payment in database
any body can help me

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('gems_stats', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('userid');
        $table->string('event');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->integer('closing_bal');
        $table->time('');
    });
}
```

Comment: use mysql enum type like, `$table->enum("type",["credit","debit"]);`

Comment: While using an enum is fine, ask yourself what if I add more types in the future such as Bitcoin etc? It may be overkill but I would be creating a new table for payment types